# How to override the materialUi AppBar default color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MaterialUI AppBar in my react application, how can I override the default color of the MUI AppBar with my preferred color ?

> My Code snippet for the Mui AppBar

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  appbar:{
    backgroundColor:'#000000',
  }
})
const Navbar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar className={classes.appbar}>
      <Toolbar>

      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: I undid your change which made it a totally different question, and totally unrelated to the original. You should never do that. If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: Actually i am restricted to asking new questions and this question is pretty much not useful to anyone, so that was the reason of my changing to a different question but sorry about that, i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a one-off customization of a component with the [`sx`-prop](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization):

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  return (
    <AppBar position="static" sx={{ color: "red", bgcolor: "black" }}>
      Content
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

[image: mui AppBar with colors manually set]

You may also be interested in [MUI's color system](https://mui.com/customization/color/).